# Find the Mapping between DataDisk Resource and Windows Server Volume

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure Windows Server VM running for several months.

Because of some historical reasons, I have two almost empty volumes on my Windows Server, I want to delete them to get rid of expensive bills.

I'm looking into ways to Delete volumes from Azure Windows Sever, and I believe you can achieve this by delete resources from Azure Portal.

However, I'm struggling finding the Mapping between DataDisk Resource and Windows Volume. (from my research, I think there likely to be an one-to-one mapping)

And for certain reason, I'm saving starting a new VM and migrate everything as the last resort.

Thanks!

---

UPDATE with details:
As I'm really struggling with this AZURE structure, I'm updating it with a lot of screenshots:

this is I have from all resources:
[image]
You can see I have 2 1TB disks, **one is premium and another is standard**
[image]
[image]
this is I have from clicking my virtual machine then click disks:
**BUT IN HERE, I END UP HAVE TWO PREMIUM DISKS**
[image]
And the following is powershell output on my Windows Server (**disk4 does not have a LUN in the output**):
[image]
[image]
[image]
**I MUST BE MISSING SOMETHING, THINGS JUST DONT ADD UP!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm struggling finding the Mapping between DataDisk Resource and
>   Windows Volume.

You are right, Azure data disk and windows Volume to be an one-to-one mapping.

We can use `get-disk` to find the windows volume information, in this way, we can find **LUN** of this volume.

Here is my test, Windows server 2016.

Run `get-disk` command in Azure VM:
[image]

Via Azure portal we can find the LUN:
[image]

In this way, we can find which Azure VM disk map to windows volume.

---

**Update:**

`Module: storage space`, this means that disk create from **storage pools**(storage space).

Like this:

[image]

In this scenario, we can use this command `Get-PhysicalDisk` to get the disk information:
[image]

Also we can find the storage pool in Azure VM:

[image]

---

> Update2:

Q1: Yes, we map Physical disk to storage pool, the create one or more disks in from this storage pool. For example, Physical disk about 1TB, we map this disk to storage pool, so the storage pool is 1TB, then we can create a disk from this storage pool, this disk should be smaller than 1TB, if we create 3 disks, disk1 + disk2 + disk3 = 1TB.

Q2: because he only create a disk from this storage pool, and the disk = 1TB, that means the disk = the storage space = TB, so the free space is 0.00B

Q3: yes, Unattached means this disk not in use at that time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, sir. There is one disk without LUN, and the model says, Storage Space. I'm wondering why.

Comment: @qichao_he  Os disk and temporary disk no link

Comment: This is not the OS disk or the temporary disk, I think. It is our 1tb F drive

Comment: @qichao_he  classic vm?

Comment: no, new one. I think the new is called Resource Manager, right

Comment: @qichao_he  where can’t you find the lun? Portal?

Comment: No, in the power shell. get-disk returns 4 disk for me with number 0,1,3,4. 3 and 4 have size 1TB, so I think its our D and F drive. I used the command you gave. disk #3 returns the same info as you gave, however for disk #4 there is no LUN in the output and the model says Storage Space

Comment: @qichao_he could you show the screenshot to your question? Could you tell me your vm size? How many disks attach to this vm? All the disk same size, 1TB?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156930/discussion-between-qichao-he-and-jason-ye-msft).

Comment: @qichao_he It means that disk create from storage space, we can use `Get-Physicaldisk` to get the LUN information, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: @qichao_he I have update my answer, please check it:)